# how can i use jquery mouseout on a div if the event is triggered when i hover over an inner element of the div?

Tags: jquery

I have a div that expands when you hover and contracts to small size when you mouseout. The only problem is the mouseout is triggered when you hover over an inner element in the div such as an image or < p >.

[example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FCxYW/1/)

this is my jquery code:

```
$(".riser").mouseover(function(){ 
 $(this).animate({height:400}, 100);
});  

$(".riser").mouseout(function(){ 
 $(this).animate({height:150}, 100);
});
```

I only want to make the div smaller when i mouseout of the div, i dont want it to do anything when i hover over the inner elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `mouseout` to `mouseleave` (and `mouseover` to `mouseenter`, although that shouldn't matter).

http://jsfiddle.net/FCxYW/2/

Comment: Unrelated, but I suggest using `.on` and `.trigger` rather than calling the event names as methods directly.